# Create Regex that accept name but not Word "to"

Tags: regex, parsing

I am working on parsing commentary of ESPNcricinfo and i want to parse following of the statements.

Example1 : Yuvraj Singh to Nasir Jamshed

Example2 : Kumar to Shoaib Malik

I write same regex both for bowler and batsman name,

Regex : `[A-Za-z[-]*]*\s[A-Za-z[-]*]*\s`

Example1 parse easily but i am facing problem in example2 like,

**"Kumar to"** consider as bowler name...

I need Help to get rid of word "to" from bowler name.

Comment: Do you need single regex for both names? Can you expect that names always will start with capital letter (is it possible to have _kumar to shoaib_)?

Comment: In ESPNCricInfo Every player name start with capital letter.

Comment: I want to exclude substring "to" from players name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following regex

```
(?<=to |^).*?(?= to|$)
```

It will work even in case of `Yuvraj Singh to Nasir Jamshed to Kumar to Shoaib Malik` string.

Ex.

```
string[] names = Regex.Matches("Yuvraj Singh to Nasir Jamshed to Kumar to Shoaib Malik", "(?<=to |^).*?(?= to|$)")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

Another option, since you definitely know that every part of the name starts with capital letter, then force the rule (`to` won't be matched by it, but trailing whitespace will):

```
([A-Z][\w-]*\s*)+
```

Comment: The First one Regex Working fine.

Comment: I thing more , why this Regex not working.
[A-Za-z[-]*]*\s[^to][A-Za-z[-]*]*\s

Comment: @MuhammadAli Because the meaning of `[^to]` is not `not 'to'`, but `none of 't', 'o' symbols`.

Comment: Is there is any possibility to get rid of "to" with my regex ?

Comment: @MuhammadAli No, you cannot say match everything, but don't include string `to` in my match. But you can use lookarounds as in my first regex (look for `to ` or beginning of string before, and look for `to` or end of string after).